# DigitalOcean droplet domain parking service not working as expected

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-parking

I'm trying to set up a domain parking service, similar to Sedo, where you can simply point your domain to my nameservers and my landing page will be displayed.

**What I've done:**

1. I set up a Digital Ocean droplet to host my website/landing page, using the Node.js quickstart configuration. This site can be found on https://www.parkedforgood.com.
2. Then I followed this [tutorial for creating vanity nameservers](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-vanity-or-branded-nameservers-with-digitalocean-cloud-servers), and created ns1/ns2/ns3.parkedforgood.com.
3. I created my glue records on NameCheap pointing to the DO nameserver IPs.
4. Then I tried to park my first domain, http://coolpatterns.net, by pointing it to ns1/ns2/ns3.parkedforgood.com.

You can see all my records at https://i.stack.imgur.com/1F5Mk.jpg.

However, the domain I parked is throwing an error: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Is something set up incorrectly or am I just mistaken as to how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, your namecheap config is right, but you need to configure a zone for `coolpatterns.net` on your DNS as well, so that the DNS server will answer queries for that domain. It just answers the following when I just tried it with `nslookup`:

```
nslookup

> server ns1.parkedforgood.com
Default Server:  ns1.parkedforgood.com
Address:  173.245.58.51

> coolpatterns.net
Server:  ns1.parkedforgood.com
Address:  173.245.58.51

*** ns1.parkedforgood.com can't find coolpatterns.net: Query refused
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a wildcard/catch-all for this, I can’t imagine the big domain parking services are manually adding each record for the millions of domains they have?

Comment: Not as such, what I imagine that they do is that they've automated the generations of records for the domain when you add a domain to their service. DNS is rather picky about these sorts of things. Or they might have some own DNS server implementation that provides the same answer regardless of what you ask it, that would basically provide that type of service.

Comment: I looked a bit further into this, and there is a thing called a wildcard record (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record), but it seems to be poorly supported, and for your implementation to work your server would have to have a wildcard record for *. which would make it answer with that to any request. This is probably how the big vendors does this. You could probably try this out with nslookup if you know the name servers for a domain parking server.

Comment: I built my own domain parking service (https://projectpending.com/) and the service automatically generates all DNS records for each added domain. The DNS implementation is custom though so it does not use zone files but DNS records are written straight into database as global key-value rows which makes handling these record much easier

Comment: That’s makes more sense, since you’re essentially need something DNS wasn’t designed to do. I need to try out my theory above though to see if I could get BIND to give the same answer to whatever query you throw at it.